# замена /n на <br />

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Заменил таким образом `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")`  но когда начинаю рендерить то почему то он просто пишет:

```
случайный текст <br />новая строчка <br />третья строчка<br />
```

Т. е. он почему то их просто так и пишет а не применяет. Обьясните пожалуйста почему так. Использую реакт.

Comment: И что показывает F12? Думаю, без подробного исходника и логов тут не обойтись...

Comment: А может надо в кавычки взять - "/\n/g"

Comment: Я могу вам сказать, что покажет F12. `&lt;br /&gt;` :)

Comment: Попробуйте так: text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

Comment: <br>. Просто <br>.

Comment: Надо уточнить дело в том что текст рендерится из props текст выглядит так в консоле реакта `случайный текст \nновая строчка \nтретья строчка\n`  а в обычной консоле он  выглядит вот так `случайный текст <br />новая строчка <br />третья строчка<br />`

Comment: Может вам для такого текста `<pre>` или `<code>` использовать, или установить соответствующий режим отображения `\n`? Тогда и заменять не прийдётся.

Comment: Ну правильно, ты взял строку, заменил в ней подстроки \n на <br/>, но чтобы строка <br/> стала обьектом в DOM дереве, надо его создать. В JQuery например есть конструкция $("body").html("<br/>какой-то текст<br/>");.  В чистом JS var br = document.createElement("br"); Думаю суть ясна.